# How can I retrieve every .bak file with PowerShell and C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I'm developing a Windows Form client application in C# .NET that allows the user to backup the database. Every time he makes a backup the following logic is executed in a sp in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @File VARCHAR (1000) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\DBCompany-'
+ (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), GETDATE(), 120),':','_'), ' ','_')+ '.bak');

BACKUP DATABASE [DBCompany]
TO DISK = @File
NAME = 'DBCompany';
GO
```

As you can see the .bak file gets a name according to the date and time it was saved, so I have differents files in my directory like these:

```
DBCompany-2015-06-04_20_21_08.bak
DBCompany-2014-02-24_19_01_39.bak
DBCompany-2014-01-22_23_30_58.bak
....
```

I know the syntax to restore a .bak file but I'm trying to make it possible for the user to select one of these files and restore it, but I can't see any way to retrieve these files and show them to him other than using a OpenFileDialog control (which I don't want to).

As far as I researched this can be done integrating PowerSheel into my C# code. Can someone point me in the right direction on how this can be done?

Comment: In a C# app? Just put them in a drop down list. Be aware that restore allows the restoration of a number of differential backups and logs so you need to consider if you want to support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this from C# without Powershell.  Assuming the app is running on the same box as the SQL Express instance, below is an example to load a combo box:

```
    var backupFileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\DBCompany", "*.bak");

    foreach(var backupFile in backupFileList)
    {
        this.comboBoxBackupFiles.Items.Add(backupFile);
    };
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Can't believe how I didn't think about it

Comment: BTW: I didn't even say I was using SQL Express and you get that info just reading the path, how cool is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the physical location of backup files, you can go with System.IO; namespace. From this

1. Get the list of files available in the physical location.
2. List all the file names and show the file names to user.
3. once the selection is made by the user restore the selected backup file.

Sorry, It could be very lengthy code to do, so I have given description to achieve your requirement.

Thanks,